# Pricing still on

Tags: magento-1.7, price, shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules, special-price

I have some products, that had some discount prices (5% off). Now I deleted all these special prices in the products' dashboard, cleared the cache multiple times and even increased the regular price. But now I still have a discount of 5% on my new regular prices. I checked cart price rules, catalog price rules and the products' pages, but there is no discount set anymore.
Where may I still look at? Where can prices also be set? ( My client has access to the dashboard of course and they sometimes do do things and have no clue what they did there actually; but I have no clue on where to check what they did wrong)

Thanks

Comment: Reindex the data again hope full it will fix you issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reindex your data and then that issue should be solved

```
Configuration -> Index Management -> Product Prices
```

Comment: Did this, but didn't work out. I though have a problem with my index management as my product flat data isn't reindexable anymore:
"Cannot initialize the indexer process."
Can the one problem be connected to the other?

Answer (score 1):

Try to click "apply rules" in catalog and cart price rules. It's kind of a reindex too :)